# PayPal api: How to get orders of user by users email?

Tags: javascript, node.js, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I want to give some benefits on my site to users who made an order or have active subscription with my merchant account.
I have nodejs server but cant find the way to query paypal for list of orders of my merchant account.

Comment: Can you please provide some code or examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PayPal would recommend you keep your own records of orders placed by a user; they are a payment processing service, not a data service, and do not want you querying their servers for this type of information.

They do offer downloadable activity logs in the www.paypal.com account interface, which can be obtained in .csv format. But that is for accounting and reconciliation purposes, not something you would want to run a script against.

Basically, you really ought to keep track of your own users' orders and active subscriptions if this information is important to you.